# how to set a factor exposure constraint for quadratic programming using cvxopt.qp?

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, quadratic, cvxopt

Trying to optimize a portfolio weight allocation here which minimize risk for a classic Markowitz portfolio. 
Let's say if I have a factor exposure constraint dataframe which denotes like

```
In [138]: exp_sub = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-10, 20],[-10, 20],[-10, 20],[-10, 20],[-10, 20]], columns=['lower','upper'])

In [131]: exp_sub
In [132]:    lower  upper
0    -10     20
1    -10     20
2    -10     20
3    -10     20
4    -10     20
```

I tried add this constraint in my code, but the solution is not correct even when the status of sol is optimal. Can anybody help? Thank you.

My codes are as below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
### Portfolio Optiimization
# Finds an optimal allocation of stocks in a portfolio,
# satisfying a minimum expected return.
# The problem is posed as a Quadratic Program, and solved
# using the cvxopt library.
# Uses actual past stock data, obtained using the stocks module.

import sys
import itertools
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers, spmatrix, sparse
from cvxopt.blas import dot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

solvers.options['show_progress'] = False

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


# solves the QP, where x is the allocation of the portfolio:
# minimize   x'Px + q'x
# subject to Gx <= h
#            Ax == b
#
# Input:  n       - # of assets
#         avg_ret - nx1 matrix of average returns
#         covs    - nxn matrix of return covariance
#         r_min   - the minimum expected return that you'd
#                   like to achieve
# Output: sol - cvxopt solution object

dates = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=6)
industry = ['industry', 'industry', 'utility', 'utility', 'consumer']
symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
zipped = list(zip(industry, symbols))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zipped)

noa = len(symbols)

data = np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10],
                 [10, 11, 10, 13, 14, 9],
                 [10, 10, 12, 13, 9, 11],
                 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8],
                 [10, 9, 12, 13, 14, 9]])

market_to_market_price = pd.DataFrame(data.T, index=dates, columns=index)
rets = market_to_market_price / market_to_market_price.shift(1) - 1.0
rets = rets.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

# covariance of asset returns
covs    = matrix(rets.cov().values)

# average yearly return for each stock
rets_mean = rets.mean()
avg_ret = matrix(rets_mean.values)
n = len(symbols)

factor_exposure = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,5)),
                               columns=list('ABCDE'))


P = covs
q = matrix(np.zeros((n, 1)), tc='d')
asset_sub = matrix(np.eye(n), tc='d')
asset_sub = matrix(sparse([asset_sub, -asset_sub]))
exp_sub = matrix(factor_exposure.values)
exp_sub = matrix(sparse([exp_sub, -exp_sub]))
# set boundary vector for h
df_asset_weight = pd.DataFrame({'lower': [0.0], 'upper': [1.0]},
                               index=list("ABCDE"))
df_asset_bnd_matrix = matrix(np.concatenate(((df_asset_weight.upper,
                                              df_asset_weight.lower)), 0))


df_factor_exposure_bound = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-10, 20],[-10, 20],[-10, 20],[-10, 20],[-10, 20]], columns=['lower','upper'])


df_factor_exposure_bnd_matrix = matrix(np.concatenate(((df_factor_exposure_bound.upper,
                                                        df_factor_exposure_bound.lower)), 0))


G = matrix(sparse([asset_sub, exp_sub]))
h = matrix(sparse([df_asset_bnd_matrix, df_factor_exposure_bnd_matrix]))

# equality constraint Ax = b; captures the constraint sum(x) == 1
A = matrix(1.0, (1, n))
b = matrix(1.0)
sol = solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library cvxportfolio is easy to solve factor exposure constraint problem.[cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/install/index.html)